# Need help finding a good code repository

Tags: repository

So I don't know if this really is a question for SO, but since I know there's a good chance a large amount of users here have experience with this subject I thought maybe I should ask. So here's the background, I've been working as the sole mobile developer for a company for the past 2 years and because of that all of the source code for the iOS, Android and Windows Phone Apps are on my local machine. We've decided to start expanding our team so that a few more developers can work with me on these projects so now I need to find a repository to put the projects into but since I really don't have any experience with any repositories I wanted to know which ones are at the top of the list so I can find one that I can use that people I interview may be familiar with as well. One caveat is that we don't want any of the source code to be publicly available (due to some of the security restrictions of the IT Department). I know I can do a google search, but like I said I wanted to get some advice from actual users instead of trying to filter through articles or reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about source control systems. Some famous tools are `Git`, `Mercurial` and `SVN`.
You can google to know the difference and decide the best solution as per your/company's requirements.

Some links to get you started:

1. [SVN wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) & [SVN Setup](http://alephzarro.com/blog/2007/01/07/installation-of-subversion-on-ubuntu-with-apache-ssl-and-basicauth/)
2. [Mercurial Setup](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/step-by-step-install-mercurial-server-on-ubuntu/)

These are open-source solutions and the setup guides are focused on Linux servers only. You can always search for setup of the same on Windows machine as well if you are looking for the same.